# online platform to search a java package name according to the method

Tags: java, import, package

For instance I copied some code and want to run them and modify them afterwards, but there are some classes or methods that could not be resolved which is due to not importing the corresponding package. For some common packages, it is easy to import them but there are some not so common packages, how could I find out what is the package name so I could import them in order to solve the "could not resolve ..." problem in Intellij ? (Actually in this case, the auto import functionality of Intellij does not work)

Comment: You need to add the appropriate libraries to the build/class path. Ask the source owner which libraries that code uses. There is no general way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool online that can find package based on the method name. However, there is a good tool available FindJar (http://www.findjar.com/) . Simply enter the name of the class or the JAR file you are looking for and start your search. findJAR.com can be used to easily resolve NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException problems.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the package/class name in the error message shown by IntellIj. If the dependent jar is a public artifact, you can search for it in the maven central repository, by giving the artifact id or group id (You can find this in the pom.xml file). This is will give you the dependent jar file, you can add it in the class path.

If possible, can you share your code snippet, so that it would be easy to identify the exact issue.